# Can't get UINavigationBar height (Custom background) with UISegmentControl

Tags: iphone, background, height, uinavigationbar, uisegmentedcontrol

I need to detect the height of the UINavigationBar

```
- (void) drawLayer:(CALayer *)layer inContext:(CGContextRef)ctx
{
    NSLog(@"NAV HEIGHT IS %d %d",self.frame.size.height, self.frame.size.width);
}
```

Prints 0 for the height

And while I'm at it why is the width 1078329344 and 1077936128?
What units are Apple using?, is it some weird calculation based on 326dpi?

Background...

I'm using the drawrect overload technique to add a custom graphic to the UINavigationBars through the App.

All good but one issue: When in landscape mode and the UINavigationBar has a UISegmentControl in it, the height increases from the shorter landscape to match the same height as portrait mode.

The code can detect the width, why can't it detect the height? 
The NSLOg below returns 0

If I could tell how high the UINavigationBar was I could swap graphics accordingly

```
- (void) drawLayer:(CALayer *)layer inContext:(CGContextRef)ctx
{
    if ([self isMemberOfClass:[UINavigationBar class]] == NO) {
        return;
    }

    UIImage *image = (self.frame.size.width > 320) ?
                        [UINavigationBar bgImageLandscape] : [UINavigationBar bgImagePortrait];

    NSLog(@"NAV HEIGHT IS %d %d",self.frame.size.height, self.frame.size.width);

    CGContextClip(ctx);
    CGContextTranslateCTM(ctx, 0, image.size.height);
    CGContextScaleCTM(ctx, 1.0, -1.0);
    CGContextDrawImage(ctx, CGRectMake(0, 0, self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.height), image.CGImage);
}
```

Above code by Ahmet Ardal (thanks)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are doing the formatting of data wrong. `%d` is for integers, but Apple uses floats for interface coordinates and sizes. So you need to use `%f` to format your string. Try changing to:

```
NSLog(@"NAV HEIGHT IS %f %f",self.frame.size.height, self.frame.size.width);
```

Comment: LOL. Nothing like making a stoopid mistake. I did search for the frame.size.height format but couldn't find anything. Probably didn't search hard enough. @PeyloW Thank you.

Comment: You also have a convenience methods for most CoreGraphics types to strings, so you could do: `NSLog(@"Nav size: %@", NSStringFromCGSize(self.frame.size));`.